# Are contacts stored in an outlook data file

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, microsoft-outlook-365

My old laptop running Windows 7 and Outlook 2010 died. I've got a new laptop running Windows 10 and Outlook 365 using POP. Someone managed to retrieve all my data files and emails from the dead laptop. But what he didn't do was retrieve the email contacts list. I have backups and I've located an outlook data file (.pst) on there named as my email address. Will the contacts list be in that file and if so, how can I retrieve it. Obviously I don't want to overwrite any new emails and contacts in Outlook 365. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook PST file contains: Email, Outlook Contacts, and Calendar. All this is in the PST and has been for a very long time.

If you have a PST file, you can definitely import Contacts from that file. You can overwrite or ignore duplicates.

Please note a point of (widespread) confusion:  Type-aheads (NK2 files and auto complete files are NOT Contacts.  These are not saved in the PST file. They can be retrieved from an old system.

[Auto complete location][1]

> Because the default folder is hidden folder, the easiest way to open
> the folder is to use the command %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook in the
> Windows Search box (or, browse to
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook). In the Outlook
> folder, find your Auto-Complete List (. nk2)

[1]: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-copy-the-auto-complete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0#:~:text=Because%20the%20default%20folder%20is,nk2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-copy-the-auto-complete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20default%20folder%20is,nk2))%20file.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with John, and you could find your contacts folder by importing the .pst file directly to your Outlook(File>Open&Export>open Outlook data file).

Besides, we actually could configure our pop account with an existing data file(.pst) in Outlook 365, so that we could find all emails and contacts in your account directly and don't need to import the file. If it also could meet your need, here are the detailed steps(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>Add>type a profile name>Add your account>Mannual setup or additional server types>POP or IMAP>configure your server, port and encription in More settings>choose **Existing Outlook data file** under *deliver new message to* and browse your datafile)

[image]